# Creating 30 empty records on create

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm working on a fitness tracking app where we encourage you to track a habit for 30 days.

Every user has_many projects, projects belong_to user, projects has_many tasks, and tasks belong_to projects.

What I'm looking to do is when a project is created, I want to populate 30 empty tasks which will be displayed in order of day, and allow the user to click on a day and update the task. (see image)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a0QU4.png)

I'm happy to post any of the code/views if you need reference.
Thanks for the help!

Comment: I recommend not to create 30 records at all. on the client side show elements by month days and not by records, while using a default values(can be create by Task.new without saving).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tasks

  def create_tasks!(n = 30)
    self.class.transaction do
      1..n.each do |day|
        self.tasks.create(day: day)
      end 
    end
  end
end
```

Wrapping [a mass insert](http://weblog.jamisbuck.org/2015/10/10/bulk-inserts-in-activerecord.html) in a single transaction is vital for performance - otherwise each insert will be run in its own transaction.

You could use a `after_create` model callback to call `create_tasks!` - but this can be problematic since the callback will fire every time you create a project which can make tests slow.

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tasks
  after_create :create_tasks!

  def create_tasks!(n = 30)
    self.class.transaction do
      1..n.each do |day|
        self.tasks.create(day: day)
      end 
    end
  end
end
```

Another way to this would be to call it in your controller:

```
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @project = Project.new(project_params)
    if @project.save
      @project.create_tasks!
      redirect_to @project
    else
      render :new
    end
  end 
end
```

Which gives you better control over exactly where in the application it happens.

Comment: This is great! Exactly what I need!

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of [Active Record's `after_create` callback](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html), which allows you to perform a task whenever a new record is created for a certain model:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :tasks

    after_create :create_empty_tasks

    private
        def create_empty_tasks
            # Create your 30 Task objects
            30.times do |i|
                Task.create(day: (i + 1), project: self) # Update to match your schema
            end
        end
end
```

You'll of course need to update that code to pass any user-specific data into the `Task`, but hopefully the callback is a good starting point.

Comment: Might wanna do `Task.create(day: (i + 1), project: self)` for assigning the new task to the project that's being created.

Comment: @FrederikSpang thanks for the suggestion, I've added that and an extra note

Comment: Well or `self.tasks << Task.create(day: (i + 1))`.. Either way would work